# SQL Statement: How does Exist return its value?

Tags: sql

```
Select * from FMN_XX.order odr where 
exists(
    select (1) from FMN_XX.order_expired exp 
    where odr.order_id = exp.order_id
);
```

Above is the example query for exists. I have tried looking around and reading about it but I just can't get my head wrapped around it.

When I query individually the query inside the **EXISTS** bracket, it returns 1 as expected and no **order_id** from **order_expired** since I didn't query for column there.

But when I run the whole query, it returns the correct number of rows! My question is, how does it know the **order_ID** from **order_expired** table when I don't even query for **order_id** from the **order_expired** table? How does it compare to get the right rows?

Extra note: Currently, in the **order** table, I have 19779 rows and in **order_expired** table, I have 8506 rows. The final result I get when I added count at the outer query layer is 8506 rows, meaning, somewhat the EXISTS statement has filters the rows. If it should just returns if at least one order_id is hit... shouldn't the whole query returns the whole 19779 rows?

Comment: Can you format your question (code part) so that it's readable?

Comment: That query basically returns the whole row of the `order` table if there is at least one record in `order_expired` with that `order_id`. I don't think there is any difficulty there. Your subquery doesn't return any id, but just something (it could even be `NULL`) when there is a match, and that's how the outer query knows the other table has a matching record.

Comment: EXISTS returns no data (values), it returns a boolean value if the SELECT inside contains data or not.

Comment: About the "extra note" : the EXISTS condition is evaluated on every correlated record.  In this case it will check the exists condition for every order_ID in the order table,  and it will return only the records that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. XD. Now I can understand it better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does it know the order_ID from order_expired table when I don't even query for order_id from the order_expired table? How does it compare to get the right rows?

The condition from `WHERE` clause of the exists's `SUBSELECT` gives this information :

the **odr.order_id** is the column from main `SELECT`, whereas 
the **exp.order_id** is the column from exists `SUBSELECT`

```
 where odr.order_id = exp.order_id
```

if the condition above returns `TRUE` then the record will appear in the result set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: Indeed. It's called a correlated sub-query. The inner results are compared to the outer results.

Comment: Oh... so that is what this is about! Oh, thank you. Now I can understand why it is behaving like this!

Answer (score 1):

Exists is similar to join - you delimit your output based on values in another table (or even the same table with different condition.).

The difference in useablity is that the exists function does not care for duplicit values, it checks only if there are query results existing with your condition.

In other words, if your table `order_expired` would be unique in column `order_id`, then you should get the same result from your query as from this query:

```
Select odr.* from FMN_XX.order odr 
join FMN_XX.order_expired exp on odr.order_id = exp.order_id;
```

However if it is not unique then the join would delimit your results, but at the same time duplicate orders from `order_expired`.

One more difference is also, that with eixsts you cant use any values from the table inside the exists subquery - with join you can use any columns from joined tables.

Comment: I'll have a run for the join statement. Thanks. XD

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> When I query individually the query inside the EXISTS bracket, it returns 1 as expected and no order_id from order_expired since I didn't query for column there.

However, I guess that you haven't *really* used the EXISTS query as it would have been:

```
select (1) from FMN_XX.order_expired exp 
 where odr.order_id = exp.order_id
```

and it would return error because it doesn't know what **odr** is.

The clause `where odr.order_id = exp.order_id` is exactly what gives the correlation between the main query and the EXISTS subquery.

So, the query would be roughly translated in natural language as:

*select all the orders that exist into the expired orders table **by looking it up by the order_id field***

Comment: Yeah, when I was requesting it individually, I added in the the table order so that it would know what the odr is but thanks for the explanation. XD